# How can I display data about a custom event on a particular page using GA4 Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

So using GTM, I designed a custom event and I am able to collect data and send it to Google Analytics.

However, the data collected is about that event in general, not about that event occurring on a specific page . I know that that Content Groups exists for Universal Analytics, but I am not sure if they are the correct way to proceed in my case (given also that I'm using a GA4 property). Or should I use Custom Reports? I am not sure.

Ideally I would like something akin to a view for each specific page with the parameters related to the event displayed. In other words, I would like to know if there is a way by which I can display in Google Analytics all the events parameters pertaining to my event but for the each of the few pages on which my event occurs. Therefore associating the event and its related data to a page.

Is this possible with Google Analytics 4?

Comment: Automatically collected parameters for events include language, page_location, page_referrer, page_title, screen_resolution. This applies to custom events as well.

page_location would be the page the event occurred on